# Calling a Module in Verilog

Tags: verilog, hardware, vivado

I just started learning hardware programming using Verilog, and I feel lost because I can't understand what errors mean.
Here, I am calling the module `reg31`

```
module nbit_register(input clk, input [31:0]in, input reset, input L,
input load, input shift, output reg[31:0] out);
always@(*)begin
if(load==1) 

  reg32 add(clk, in, reset,L, out);
  
   else
        out={ in[30:0],1'b0};
   end
    
   endmodule
```

But, I get this error:

> error: syntax error near "reg32"

This is what the module looks like

```
module reg32(
    input clk,
    input [31:0] in,
    input rst,
    input  L,
    output  [31:0] out
    );
```

Can someone point out the mistake here?

Comment: Basically, you don't call a module in the same way as you don't call an IC. You instantiate a module and when you solder down an IC you are "instantiating" it.

Comment: I understood - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you want to "select" and make module `reg32` "work" in a `if` branch.

Imaging a cell phone PCB board. The speaker unit is just out there, even if it's in silent mode. So instantiate `reg32` separately, then use your own logic to deal with the nets connected to `reg32`.

```
wire [31:0] add_out;
reg32 add(clk, in, reset,L, add_out); // here the 4 inputs are connected to top inputs
                                      // directly. but if you want, you can use 'load'
                                      // to control them similar to the code below.

always@(*)begin
  if(load==1)
    out = add_out;
  else
    out = { in[30:0],1'b0};
  end
```

If you're mainly working on software, you need to be familiar to thinking in a "hardware" way.